# Azure CosmosDB: Read exactly one document via Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDb API

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb, microsoft-azure-documentdb

I am querying DocumentDB using LINQ and want to read only one document e.g. FirstOrDefault. What's the right way to do that? Here's the code that may give me multiple documents. How should I modify it so that it reads only the first document?

```
dynamic doc = from f in client.CreateDocumentQuery(collection.DocumentsLink)
              where f.Id == userId.ToString()
              select f;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply `FirstOrDefault` on your result:-

```
dynamic doc = (from f in client.CreateDocumentQuery(collection.DocumentsLink)
              where f.Id == userId.ToString()
              select f).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: In that particular example, how would that query match more than one document as the query is on the id field ?

Comment: @mmg666 - A user may have multiple documents, so OP wanna fetch the first document in DB for that particular user.